# How to solve 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields' in Graphene-django

Tags: python, django, graphene-django, django-graphql-jwt

Have this mutation

```
class AddStudentMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        input = StudentInputType()
    
    student = graphene.Field(StudentType)
    
    @classmethod
    @staff_member_required
    def mutate(cls, root, info, input):
        try:
            _student = Student.objects.create(**input)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise Exception("Student already created")
        return AddStudentMutation(student=_student)
```

Before executing the above mutation in `graphiql`, I add the request header `"Authorization": "JWT <token>"` so that the user is authorized.
But I get the error `graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fields'`.
The error doesn't occur when I remove the header. It also works fine when I include it in requests for queries. Am I doing something wrong? I need the authorization to happen for mutations too.

I tracked the Traceback and it leads to file `.../site-packages\graphql_jwt\middleware.py`. It appears it's a bug in the package in function `allow_any()`  line 18 `field = info.schema.get_type(operation_name).fields.get(info.field_name)`. New to this I need help.

I'm using `graphene-django==2.15.0` and `django-graphql-jwt==0.3.4`

Answer (score 2):

The `allow_any` function that comes with `django-graphql-jwt` is expecting somehow to be used with Queries not Mutations. So you may overwrite the `allow_any` function by adding the native `try/except` block:

```py
def allow_any(info, **kwargs):
    try:
        operation_name = get_operation_name(info.operation.operation).title()
        operation_type = info.schema.get_type(operation_name)

        if hasattr(operation_type, 'fields'):

            field = operation_type.fields.get(info.field_name)

            if field is None:
                return False

        else:
            return False

        graphene_type = getattr(field.type, "graphene_type", None)

        return graphene_type is not None and issubclass(
            graphene_type, tuple(jwt_settings.JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES)
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return False
```

and in your `settings.py` you have to add the path of the overwritten `allow_any` function:

```
GRAPHQL_JWT = {
      'JWT_ALLOW_ANY_HANDLER': 'path.to.middleware.allow_any'
}
```

I hope this may solve your problem as it worked with me